# Apply External CSS to HTML Nodes as Inline Style (vanilla Javascript/Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, coffeescript

So, I have an SVG file that is being embedded into my HTML, uncompressed (retaining its original, nodal format). It contains several groups, all but three of which are hidden (display == "none"). Based on the user's options, I am dynamically toggling the hidden and visible groups, utilizing a parent class mapped to the appropriate visibility options. My goal is to take the resulting SVG node, inline the applied styling corresponding with the parent class, and submitting it to the server when the user is done for processing as a raster image.

Is there a swift, cross-browser-compliant way to iterate over all styles applied to a node and inline them with a script, prior to me taking the entire node tree and converting it to a string? A vanilla JavaScript/CoffeeScript solution is ideal. [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io) is available, if needed.

I ask, as it looks like my only other option would be porting the dynamic styling to JavaScript, introducing unwanted rigidity (more complex updates on account of multiple points requiring editing, et cetera).

Comment: You could iterate over the values returned by `window.getComputedStyle()` and write them to the element's `style` property.

Answer (score 0):

[SVG permits `style` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style).

You should be able to put your CSS rules defining the parent classes in a `style` element **within** the SVG. Then toggle your groups as you are doing now. If you now send the entire SVG fragment to your rasterizer, including the `style` tag internal to it, it will have all the necessary CSS information and should be able to render the SVG correctly, **without** you having to go through the entire tree and inline all the styles.